# Use preg_match_all to filter <a> TAG text

Tags: php, html, regex

im trying to get the text from this links

The full  tag

```
<a href="/wiki/Correa_(apellido)" title="Correa (apellido)">Correa</a>
```

My code

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Apellidos_m%C3%A1s_comunes_en_Espa%C3%B1a_e_Hispanoam%C3%A9rica");

preg_match_all('%<a href="/wiki/.*?_(apellido)" title=".*? (apellido)">(.*?)</a>%i', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    echo $result[1][$i];
}
```

But is not working, what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't use regexp to part HTML, use a DOM parser library.

Comment: can you please wire an example solution

Comment: No I can't, it's too much work. You should do your own research to learn how to use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: I should work with preg_match_all  right ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be using regular expressions at all. You should use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Actually it is ok to extract a text from html with regex. Yep, regex cannon handle xml/html document **structure**, but it still able to extract simple string values enclosed by a single document element.

Answer (score 0):

This would save you for the time being:

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*>(.*)<\/a>/imU', $html, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain all the text values (if I understand your request correctly). But as Barmar suggests, you really should consider using the [DOMDocument](http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) parsing functions instead.

**Edit:** If you only look for those URLs that have "apellido" in its "href" or "title", you have to modify it as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*apellido.*".*>(.*)<\/a>/imU', $html, $matches);
```

Be aware though that this can give you a false positive if "apellido" occurs in some other `a`'s attribute other than "title" or "href".

Comment: this shows all a link text, but I only need links where this word is present (apellido) on the title or href

Comment: You should have described it clearer in your question. I have modified my answer.